# Make div (display: table) match outer container's height width min-height

Tags: css, html-table

I need container width min-height in order to hold variable size content, but at the same time I need content to be vertically aligned inside parent container.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mr_goodcat/n5Pq3/6/

**HTML:**

```
<table class="mainLayout">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="contentLayout">
                <div class="tbl">
                    <div class="tcell">
                        <div class="inner">
                            CONTENT
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>                             
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            BOTTOM
        </td>          
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mainLayout {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.contentLayout {
    width: 100%;    
    min-height: 200px;    
    border: 1px solid red;   
    display: block;
}

.tbl {
     height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.tcell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: purple;
    display: table-cell;    
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

Want to align purple box inside red square (min-height containter). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/n5Pq3/30/ This is a known issue with webkit. The work around is to use

```
position:relative; //on parent 

position:absolute; // on child
```

Want to look into more detail then follow this link ...https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559

Comment: Works like magick! THANKS A LOT!

A bit updated fiddle, which vertically aligns content: http://jsfiddle.net/mr_goodcat/E3TKS/